# Space between paragraphs in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, line-spacing

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]

  \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I control the space between paragraphs (insert more space of a predefined amount)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip} % for example

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]

  \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]